# Create a list of lists, List as look up table

Tags: python

I need to create list of lists according to the result from a list as a look up table

List

```
lists=['a','b','c']
```

Data

```
[
  {'rank': 1, 'keyword_name': 'keyword1', 'volume': None, 'asin': 'a'},
  {'rank': 30, 'keyword_name': 'keyword2', 'volume': None, 'asin': 'b'}
  {'rank': 4, 'keyword_name': 'keyword3', 'volume': 123, 'asin': 'c'}

  {'rank': 5, 'keyword_name': 'keyword3', 'volume': None, 'asin': 'c'}
]
```

so the new list of lists would be

```
// format of result

keyword_name|volume|rank


result = [
    ['keyword1',None,1],
    ['keyword2',None,30],
    ['keyword3',123,4],
    ['keyword3',None,5]
]
```

My initial code in mind is like below

```
results = []
for list in lists:
    for res in data:
        if res['asin'] == list:
           results.append(res)
```

But we all know it will not work.I need the result to put as data to pandas dataframe, But I have no idea how to achieve it

```
 import pandas as pd


 df = pd.DataFrame(data=results, columns=lists)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply use `pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)`

```
data = [
  {'rank': 1, 'keyword_name': 'keyword1', 'volume': None, 'asin': 'a'},
  {'rank': 30, 'keyword_name': 'keyword2', 'volume': None, 'asin': 'b'},
  {'rank': 4, 'keyword_name': 'keyword3', 'volume': 123, 'asin': 'c'},
  {'rank': 5, 'keyword_name': 'keyword3', 'volume': None, 'asin': 'c'}
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
```

Comment: I'm still new in dataframes, and I tried you answer `df = pd.DataFrame(data=joined, columns=asin_list)` `print df` and I got NAN except for `volumes`

Answer (score 1):

Or even simply:

```py
df = pd.Dataframe(data)
```